# Run java code inside javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, api, jar

I want to build a site that calls a pi and displays the results. The problem is the API is a jar file that i normally import into a java project and go from there. However i want to build a web app but not sure i how can interact with my jar file.

I see some folks executing the jar in a  command line but im not sure that the same, i want to interact with all the methods exposed to me via this java API by the jar file.

any ideas if there is a popular way of doing this or a framework i could use?

Comment: As far as I know, JS will not be able to interact with your jar file.  You need to build a web app (with like a servlet or a service) and your server-side code (in the servlet or service) will be the one interacting with the `.jar` - The output of your webapp is then displayed in your HTML page (which does not require javascript by the way).  Oh, a Java ***is not*** JavaScript (just in case you are not clear on that).

Comment: You can look into Spring MVC or similar web frameworks to start with. Like   ochi mentioned, these frameworks can interact with your jar and produce webapges which it sends to browser as a response to requests.

Comment: Are you using NodeJS?  If so, you can run your jar file in a child process. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Comment: Hi, i am not planning to use anything but would like to keep the complexity down by sticking with java as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring MVC, you can build web apps there, consume the API jar file and do whatever you want in the views(frontend) with javascript and so on.

I recommend you use [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/), which is pretty simple and easy.

If you want to build a fast app I also recommend you to use spring boot

You will build an app within minutes

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/
```

Comment: Great - i'll check it out. I probably shouldnt have mentioned javascript as any web tech will do me!

Comment: with thymeleaf you can do things you normally do with a plain html, like javascript, css (bootstrap and others) and still have connectivity with your java core